# Where else could /usr/local/lib/php be?

Tags: php, pear, include-path

I'm developing an application in PHP on a Linux server. The server has at least two different versions of php installed on it: 5.2.0 and 5.2.9.

The 5.2.0 version has the following directory `/usr/local/lib/php` in the `include_path` in php.ini.

**I need to find out where the 5.2.9 version of this directory is located.**

I checked the `include_path` setting in the 5.2.9 php.ini but it only has `.` and `/usr/share/pear` for `include_path`.

(Note that I just installed pear right now, since the 5.2.9 php was originally configured without pear.) The files in `/usr/share/pear` do not seem to match what I see in `/usr/local/lib/php` and it seems a little absurd to tell pear that `php_dir` is `/usr/share/pear`. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** - Is it possible that `/usr/local/lib/php` also belongs to php 5.2.9? Is there anything within this directory itself I can look at, to see?

Answer (score 2):

If the directory you're looking for exists (it might not if you excluded pear during install): The default location would be `/xxx/lib/php` where `/xxx` is the installation prefix.

For example, on one of my servers, one of my PHP executables (I have 4 versions installed) is located `/custom/php5.3.5/bin/php` so it's corresponding PEAR/general library directory is `/custom/php5.3.5/lib/php`

(`/custom/php5.3.5` being the installation prefix, normally it would be `/usr/local` or `/usr`.)

If your lib/php directory has a pearcmd.php file, call `(yourphpbin) pearcmd.php info pear` and it should be able to tell you pear version, it's requirements and whatnot.  (If pearcmd.php exists, there's a good chance pear exists in that directory.)  The pear shell-script would by default be at `/xxx/bin/pear` again `/xxx` being the installation prefix.

As far as I'm aware, you can set it up so that PEAR is shared among multiple versions of PHP.  I would assume that's how the `/usr/share/pear` one is set up.  (Distribution repository-provided?)  Not sure if the same holds true for `pecl`.  If you have multiple installs of pear, you just need to make sure you install the packages you want to use into the right pear install.

PHP will happily use whatever PEAR installation you tell it to in include_path.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **whereis** command. It usualy gets you the binary, man page and configuration paths.

> $ whereis php

You can then check the information each PHP version outputs:

> $ /path/to/php.binary -i

There should be information about the included paths and configuration files used.

Comment: See my comment(s) on the other answers, and also the UPDATE in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To find it, use:

```
]# sudo updatedb
]# locate php
```

That might return LOTS of results, you can filter in various ways. I usually try this first:

```
]# locate php | grep bin
```

Comment: I know where the binary executable is for php 5.2.9, so this doesn't help. /usr/local/lib/php looks like a library directory and doesn't have anything to do with bin. I'll see what I can find this way, but the other problem is, if I find a directory that appears to be correct, I'm not sure how to verify which version of php it is actually associated with (we might have more than 2 versions installed!).

Comment: Same process, `locate php | grep lib` and such. Might be in lib64. When I've installed a new version of PHP, both by yum-type installers and compiling, it overwrites the old one. The only time it's different is if I have 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command in the console:

```
    which php
```

Comment: I know where the binary executable is for php 5.2.9, so this doesn't help. `/usr/local/lib/php` looks like a library directory and doesn't have anything to do with executables.